# Using Token Authentication in django, but i need to get user session length?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a otp based user login in DRF and generating a Token for user signup and otp is matched , now i want to calculate the session  length of each user on the platform , how to do this in DRF.

Comment: I really think it's best to try and do it yourself, then post about a specific error you're having.

Comment: Is there any example i can refer or some explanation as i am new to this